# Generate a Synthetic Bivariate Data for Testing Simple Linear Regression Using Excel

Tags: regression, excel, synthetic-data

I come up with a solution as below. What do you think? Do you have any other way?

Linear regression modeled as;

```
y(i) = a + b*x(i) + e(i)
```

*a* and *b* is constant, thus for all value of *i*;

```
a = RAND()*(U_a - L_a) + L_a
b = RAND()*(U_b - L_b) + L_b
```

*U_a* and *L_a* is upper and lower bound for *a*

*U_b* and *L_b* is upper and lower bound for *b*.

*x(i)* is a variable, thus for all value of *i*;

```
x(1) = RAND()*(U_x - L_x) + L_x
x(2) = RAND()*(U_x - L_x) + L_x
...
x(n-1) = RAND()*(U_x - L_x) + L_x
x(n) = RAND()*(U_x - L_x) + L_x
```

*U_x* and *L_x* is upper and lower bound for *x*.

*e(i)* is a variable, normally distributed with mean *0*, thus for all value of *i*;

```
e(1) = NORM.INV(RAND(),m,s)
e(2) = NORM.INV(RAND(),m,s)
...
e(n-1) = NORM.INV(RAND(),m,s)
e(n) = NORM.INV(RAND(),m,s)
```

*m* is mean which is equal to *0* and *s* is standard deviation.

therefore, variable *y(i)* for all value of *i*;

```
y(1) = a + b*x(1) + e(1)
y(2) = a + b*x(2) + e(2)
...
y(n-1) = a + b*x(n-1) + e(n-1)
y(n) = a + b*x(n) + e(n)
```

please note that, *a* and *b* is constant. Therefore, they only have single random value each. So, when dragging, use cell reference and anchor to avoid generating multiple *a* and *b*.

Scatter plot variable *y(i)* versus *x(i)*

The result seems OK each time I press F9. But, I am not sure if this is the right way to do and I am intrigued if there is other better way.